# Problems executing a condition in php

Tags: php

```
$press=$_GET['sell'];
echo $press;  //OUTPUT IS : SELL
if($press == SELL)
{
   header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: delete the echo before the if, or comment it and enclose SELL into quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a single/double quotation

```
if($press=='SELL')
```

on the other hand, you must not send any output such as echo before `header`. So, do not echo anything before header.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.. Enclose the **`SELL`** under single quotes.

This works if your URL is in the format like .. `http://yourwebsite.com/yourfile.php?sell=SELL`

```
<?php
$press=$_GET['sell'];    
if($press == 'SELL')
         {
            header("Location: home.php");
         }
```

Comment: THANKS FOR ANSWER BUT NOT WORKING.

Comment: Can you explain `NOT WORKING` ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot single quote

```
if($press == 'SELL')
 {
    header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to put SELL in quotes like 'SELL'
2. You must not output anything before you send any headers

Answer (score 0):

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

remove

```
echo $press;  OUTPUT IS : SELL
```